# How to setup ISV Local cache using local host & ISV Client Agent

Tags: apache, caching, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I was going through the MS Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/deploy/express-update-delivery-isv-support

where it talks about setting up Express installation through WSUS Server. I'm able to setup 'ISV file cache using HTTP Server' and No idea about the second method.i.e. 'ISV Local cache using local host & ISV Client Agent' Can some one help me in setting up the second scenario. Or redirect me to some documents where I can get helps.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run a local server in agent machine, This can be of any web server which serves http requests. with python we can have a up and running http server with one line of code.